# Insert item into zsh array

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Let's say I have an array defined as such:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
    os_icon
    dir
    vcs
    newline
    prompt_char
  )
```

Now I want to insert an item `my_item` into the array after `vcs`.  I don't know what index `vcs` is at, all I know is that I want to insert it right after `vcs`

I tried

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS:s/vcs/vcs my_item})
```

But for some reason that does not work.  The followed does work for substitution:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS:s/vcs/my_item})
```

But of course will remove vcs.... I'm obviously not getting the space correct, but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you knew the index, you could simply assign an array slice to the index of vcs:

```bash
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[2]=(vcs my_item)
```

As you don't know the index, but are sure the element can only exist once, just assign to the first matching index:

```bash
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[(i)vcs]}]=(vcs my_item)
```

Transcript of a shell session to try this out:

```bash
 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
    os_icon
    dir
    vcs
    newline
    prompt_char
  )


 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ echo ${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[3]}
vcs

 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ echo ${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[4]}
newline

 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[(i)vcs]}]=(vcs my_item)

 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ echo ${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[3]}
vcs

 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ echo ${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[4]}
my_item

 /tmp                                                                                                                                                 [9:10]
 ❯ echo ${POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS[5]}
newline
``
```